# How are the account "pictures" used in Mist generated?

Tags: accounts, mist

In mist, all accounts have a colourful pixelated "profile picture" used to identify them. For instance, in this screenshot from the Mist releases page, the Dogecoin Bounty DAO is given a purple profile pic. How are these generated?

[image]

Comment: Using https://github.com/ethereum/blockies But with the same hash of a mist wallet but it generates a different identicon, is there anything to be added to the hash or blockies options for them to be the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They use a customized version of the [blockies](https://github.com/download13/blockies) library, namely this one: https://github.com/alexvandesande/blockies.

Our port has a few graphical fixes as well as a significant fix to avoid duplicate icons in the original version caused by a bad random number generator. The upstream author doesn't want to accept the good PR since it breaks existing icons for existing users, so for the foreseeable future, we'll use a fork and not the upstream lib.

Comment: Are they generated local to each copy of Mist, or would the same contract always have the same icon?

Comment: They are generated based on the address of an account/contract. It will look the same on all machines (as long as they use the same library/algorithm to generate it).

Comment: What does metamask use?