# How do you generate an address identicon using javascript?

Tags: accounts, addresses, javascript

Given an address, how do you generate its identicon using javascript?

Comment: Not really an Ethereum question - Use one of the many identicon javascript libraries and generate based on the address.

Comment: This was already answered in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/how-are-the-account-pictures-used-in-mist-generated/1900#1900 :)

Comment: Oh thanks so much. I didn't find it because I searched for "identicon"