# Mist hash Identicon

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Upon finding this thread
[How are the account "pictures" used in Mist generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/how-are-the-account-pictures-used-in-mist-generated/39099)

I tried to use this version of [blockies](https://github.com/alexvandesande/blockies) to generate the identicon based on a wallet/contract hash

Although i get a different identicon from the one that Mist generates.
Is there anything to be added/removed to the hash or blockies options for it to generate identical icons?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking in the [`versions`](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/5d3b371c24d8b09d111356209fa895c76bfe1fb9/interface/.meteor/versions) file for Mist, it seems to use the following:

```
alexvandesande:identicon@2.0.2
```

...which can be found in the AtmosphereJS Meteor repository, [here](https://atmospherejs.com/alexvandesande/identicon).

In the README:

> Client-side identicon generation for Meteor **using a 3 color variation
>   of  blockies.**

I haven't dug into what the implementation differences are - I'll leave that fun to you :-)

Comment: The question was exactly asking for the implementation but thanks anyway